# after a post my req.body is empty with body-parser

Tags: node.js, express, post, body-parser

when i post my form, i have a empty object return by body-parser

thank you for your help ;-)

I tried for config of body-parser : "extended: false" and "extended: true" but same result

server :

```
// Dependencies
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let config = require ('../config.js');
let app = express();

// Template
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Middleware
app.use('/assets', express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Route
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.render('pages/index')
});

app.post('/result', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body) // result = {}
})

app.listen(config.port);

console.log("Let's go on port :", config.port);
```

html :

```
<form action="/result" method="post" class = "form-group">


    <label for = "hp">Index heure pleine</label>
    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "hp" placeholder = "Entrer index heure pleine">

    <label for = "hc">Index heure creuse</label>
    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "hc" placeholder = "Entrer index heure creuse">

    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Envoyer</button>

</form>
```

Comment: What would you expect in the body after a POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of a HTTP post is a key/value hash of all the form controls with a name attribute, and the value is the value of the control.

You need to give names to all your inputs.